# How to call call graph api in the azure function by using timer trigger and PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-ad-graph-api

How to call graph api in the azure function by using timer trigger  and, output of graph api will be stored in the blob table? This solution will use the visual studio code and power shell. 
Reference link :https://dev.to/azure/use-azure-function-to-clean-up-your-mess-automatically-3h29

Answer (score 1):

Please tell us where you are facing problem. If you want to learn concepts then i have shared some references

Time triggered azure function
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=csharp

Graph Api is very broad so share in which part you have problem. Basic concepts can cover in below microsoft link
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/

Azure Storage and blob
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet

Comment: Thanks, however, I need a specific link that help me create my timer.

Comment: I hv already shared all links with you and if you are looking specific link which solve your problem then i think it will be hard to find that. Let me know if u need any other help